# Link login page of facebook on the button click in android app

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i want that when i click a button ,facebook login page should be open to login facebook account .how can it be achieved.please help me..

Comment: Google it please. Or follow these links https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: Google ? What's that ?

Answer (score 0):

While click on button put this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/login?_rdr=p"));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Facebook login page will open in browser.